# Spring AMQP RabbitMQ InboundChannelAdapter and OutboundEndpoint Different Serialization/Deserialization Strategy

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a class:

```java
public class SomeClass implements Serializable {
    private String name;

    public static SomeClass valueOf(String value) {
        // Here validate and return SomeClass
    }
}
```

Serializers/Deserializers for it:

```java
public class SomeClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SomeClass> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(SomeClass someClass, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeString(someClass.getName());
    }
}

public class SomeClassDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<SomeClass> {

    @Override
    public SomeClass deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        final String name = ((TextNode) parser.getCodec().readTree(parser)).textValue();
        return SomeClass.valueOf(name);
    }
}
```

In my `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` configuration:

```java
builder.serializerByType(SomeClass.class, new SomeClassSerializer());
builder.deserializerByType(SomeClass.class, new SomeClassDeserializer());
```

And everything works smoothly when `SomeClass` is in the body of an `POST`/`GET` requests. However, with Spring integration I have:

```java
return Amqp
           .inboundAdapter(container)
           .outputChannel(someClassChannel)
           .messageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapperBuilder.build()))
           .get();
```

and for the the outbound:

```java
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "someChannel")
public AmqpOutboundEndpoint someOutboundEndpoint(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate,
                                                               FanoutExchange exchange) {
    return Amqp
               .outboundAdapter(rabbitTemplate)
               .exchangeName(exchange.getName())
               .get();
}
```

With my `RabbitTemplate` config:

```java
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder){
    final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapperBuilder
            .serializerByType(SomeClass.class, new SomeClassSerializer())
            .build()));
    return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

And my `Gateway`:

```java
@Gateway(requestChannel = "someChannel")
void publishEvent(@Header(value = "someClass") SomeClass someClass, @Payload Object payload);
```

When I send the message, I get an exception in my `SomeClassDeserializer` calling `valueOf` method of `SomeClass` (I throw the `InvalidArgumentException`):

Full stack trace:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@43a251c4]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass] for value 'com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass@ec7887e4'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't convert value : com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass@ec7887e4 into a valid com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass object, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=com.company.project.security.domain.client.Client@55095ce3, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=com.company, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=com.company.web.192.168.1.34, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, json__TypeId__=com.company.project.security.domain.client.Client, amqp_timestamp=Fri Oct 30 12:13:00 EET 2020, amqp_messageId=1dffe404-2235-4f79-4a14-315c896c3c4e, id=bcaa71d5-b454-e65c-6939-b9f07b7cc47b, event=com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass@ec7887e4, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-ImFjO9LBGoks9Lm3E0EkbQ, contentType=application/json, __TypeId__=com.company.project.security.domain.client.Client, timestamp=1604049180277}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.access$000(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher$1.run(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:204)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass] for value 'com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass@ec7887e4'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't convert value : com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass@ec7887e4 into a valid com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass object
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToObjectConverter.convert(ObjectToObjectConverter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:111)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:148)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:580)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:476)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:355)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:108)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't convert value : com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass@ec7887e4 into a valid com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass object
    at com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass.valueOf(SomeClass.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToObjectConverter.convert(ObjectToObjectConverter.java:102)
```

From trying to deserialize `SomeClass` with it's `valueOf` method, I see that the deserializer is using the correct deserializer. However, the value it's trying to deserialize, `com.company.project.SomeClass@ec7887e4` is not the outcome of the serializer I provide (though I provide the needed serializer to `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` in `RabbitTemplate` configuration). Could it be a bug, or what am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Here's another unexpected behavior:

I have temporarily switched `SomeClassDeserializer` to:

```java
public class SomeClassDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<SomeClass> {

    @Override
    public SomeClass deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        final String name = ((TextNode) parser.getCodec().readTree(parser)).textValue();
        return new SomeClass(name);
    }
}
```

and the `valueOf` method on `SomeClass` kept calling instead of `new SomeClass(name)` on the new `SomeClassDeserializer`. It's the moment I switched the name of the static method from `valueOf` to `valueOfName` my actual new implementation started getting called.

Since there's no validation on the constructor of `SomeClass`, the exception goes, although this time it started to deserialize as

```java
new SomeClass("com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass@ec7887e4")
```

instead of

```java
new SomeClass("myActualValue")
```

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Comment: @GaryRussell I've added another behavior I was not expecting, if it's of any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Couldn't convert value : com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass@ec7887e4 into a valid com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass

It looks like are just sending the class name as a String.

com.company.project.domain.package.SomeClass@ec7887e4

This is the default `toString()` implementation on `Object`.

i.e. `SomeClass.getName()` instead of `someClass.getName()` (assuming there is a `getName()` method on the class.

**EDIT**

I didn't notice it was a header, sorry.

The message converter only performs conversion on the payload.

For headers, you need to implement a custom `HeaderMapper` - Spring just passes headers to the amqp-client, which does a `toString()` on types it doesn't know.

Subclass the `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper` and override `populateUserDefinedHeader` on the outbound side and `extractUserDefinedHeaders` on the inbound side.

Comment: That's my point. Shouldn't the `SomeClassSerializer` isn't used, in the same way my `SomeClassDeserializer` is being used? Or, is my deserializer not being used but only the constructor with `SomeClass(String name)` is being called for? i.e. The custom serialization/deserialization for `@Header` is not supported?

Comment: I've checked. `SomeClassDeserializer` is not being called as well. So I'm guessing custom serialization and deserialization ıs not supported for `@Header`s.

Comment: Oh; It's a header - sorry - missed that - see the edit; you need a custom header mapper.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought custom serializers were being used for serialization/deserialization for headers. Now I did exactly what you suggested and the issue is gone. Thank you.